# Word meaning "asymmetry" but with positive connotation

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that means "asymmetry" or "asymmetrical" that has a positive connotation?

"Harmony" comes to mind, but seems like a glancing shot. If anything, it indirectly implies an asymmetry.

EDIT: There are many situations where asymmetry is good. When two parties share their competitive advantages in trade, for instance.

Comment: I'm not sure that I would infer asymmetry from the use of the word harmony. I'm also not sure that I would necessarily take asymmetry as being negative.

Comment: Well, harmony in music at least occurs when two sounds that are different are pleasing when played together.

Comment: I agree that "asymmetry" is a neural term, but there are several neutral/negative ways to refer to the concept: "unfair", "lopsided", "imbalanced", "tilted", "skewed", "uneven" and I'm looking for a positive one.

Comment: Are you thinking of *diversity*? Could even be *variety*, depending on context. Give us the broader context alolng with a sample sentence.

Comment: I don't think harmony implies asymmetry at all, if anything it implies balance.

Comment: If you're looking for a metaphor, how about *syncopation*?

Comment: To me, *jaunty* connotes stylish obliqueness.

Answer (score 2):

Complementary and counterbalanced could possibly be what you're looking for. Some other [words for asymmetrical](https://www.crosswordsolver.com/clue/ASYMMETRICAL) with positive connotations include rococo, fantastic, and extravagant. Unsystematic could also have a positive connotation in certain situations.